# I liked vs I like

Tags: grammaticality, tense

Which one in the following is grammatical?

> I **liked** the above chart as it clearly lays out the scope of each team and
>   helps everyone to understand how teams are aligned for the mission.
>
> I **like** the above chart as it clearly lays out the scope of each team and
>   helps everyone to understand how teams are aligned for the mission.

Answer (score 1):

Both, with different meaning:

The former expresses the speaker's reaction *in the past*, presumably at the time they first saw the chart. Their opinion may or may not have changed since.

The latter expresses their attitude towards it *now*. It is not very probable in this context, but it might be possible that the speaker hated it at the first impression; we can't know.